Separating the Primary and Secondary Axes from Each other for a graph in Excel
I somehow managed to get both my Primary and Secondary Axes on the same side.
For my first Graph, I added a secondary axis: no issues.
I then copied the graph and changed the input data and now both axes are on the same side.
Can anyone help me split them again?

